# Make Numpy Symmetric Matrix from a list of pairs

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a correlation matrix, but specified as pairs, like:

```py
cm = pd.DataFrame({'name1': ['A', 'A', 'B'], 
                   'name2': ['B', 'C', 'C'], 
                   'corr': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]})
cm
    name1   name2   corr
0   A       B       0.1
1   A       C       0.2
2   B       C       0.3
```

What is the simplest way to make this into a numpy 2d array correlation matrix?

```
    A   B   C
A 1.0 0.1 0.2
B 0.1 1.0 0.3
C 0.2 0.3 1.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about `pure numpy` since you are dealing with a pandas dataframe. Here's a *pure pandas* solution:

```
s = cm.pivot(*cm)

ret = s.add(s.T, fill_value=0).fillna(1)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
A  1.0  0.1  0.2
B  0.1  1.0  0.3
C  0.2  0.3  1.0
```

---

**Extra**: for reverse (`ret` is as above)

```
(ret.where(np.triu(np.ones(ret.shape, dtype=bool),1))
    .stack()
    .reset_index(name='corr')
)
```

Output:

```
  level_0 level_1  corr
0       A       B   0.1
1       A       C   0.2
2       B       C   0.3
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! Could you explain what cm.pivot(*cm)  does?

Comment: @MachineLearner `*cm` is essentially equivalent to `*list(cm.column)`. So in this case the line is equivalent to `cm.pivot('name1','name2', 'corr')`.

Comment: What is the reverse? How do you use `melt` to go from `s` back to `cm`?

Comment: @Jonathan see the added extra.

Answer (score 3):

One way could be to build a graph using `networkX`, setting the `corr` column as edge `weight`, and obtain the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) using [`nx.to_pandas_adjacency`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_pandas_adjacency.html):

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(cm.rename(columns={'corr':'weight'}), 
                            source='name1', 
                            target='name2', 
                            edge_attr ='weight')

G.edges(data=True)
# EdgeDataView([('A', 'B', {'weight': 0.1}), ('A', 'C', {'weight': 0.2}), 
#               ('B', 'C', {'weight': 0.3})])

adj = nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G)
# sets the diagonal to 1 (node can't be connected to itself)
adj[:] = adj.values + np.eye(adj.shape[0])
```

---

```
print(adj)

    A    B    C
A  1.0  0.1  0.2
B  0.1  1.0  0.3
C  0.2  0.3  1.0
```

Comment: Very clever and nice solution! Let's see if we can use plain numpy, but this is certainly a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the last column is sorted in an appropriate manner we could use the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# define data frame
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'name1': ['A', 'A', 'B'],
    'name2': ['B', 'C', 'C'],
    'correlation': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]})

# get correlation column and dimension
correlation = data['correlation'].values
dimension = correlation.shape[0]

# define empty matrix to fill and unit matrix
matrix_upper_triangular = np.zeros((dimension, dimension))

# fill upper triangular matrix with one half at diagonal
counter = 0
for (row, column), element in np.ndenumerate(matrix_upper_triangular):
    # half of diagonal terms
    if row == column:
        matrix_upper_triangular[row, column] = 0.5
    # upper triangular values
    elif row < column:
        matrix_upper_triangular[row, column] = correlation[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        pass

# add upper triangular + lower triangular matrix
correlation_matrix = matrix_upper_triangular
correlation_matrix += matrix_upper_triangular.transpose()
```